# Keyboard shortcut Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Does the keyboard shortcut for moving from editor to console back and forth in Sublime Text 2 exist? If so what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Python Code block you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (The single quote on the tilde key).  There are some other useful shortcuts here:
[Useful Shortcuts](https://gist.github.com/1736542)

Not sure if this helps with other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although i did not realised that by keying show console is basically the same with moving the cursor to the console.